# How should I build an entity recognition model from this text files

Tags: python, nlp, named-entity-recognition

this might be a little naive question but bear with me.

I have a dataset like this.

> ```
> Pretty    O
> bad   O
> storm O
> here  O
> last  O
> evening   O
> . O
>
> From  O
> Green O
> Newsfeed  O
> : O
> AHFA  B-group
> extends   O
> deadline  O
> for   O
> Sage  O
> Award O
> to    O
> Nov   O
> . O
> ```

where **O** is tag for non entity, similarly **B-group** is tag for a group. similarly some other entities are there.

and I am trying to build an **name entity recognition** model. All the models I have came across has sentences and then they go on building a model. Like they directly get PoS tagging for all the words from API by processing them.

but if I want to train a model here.
Can someone suggest me an approach, or direct me towards a resource. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe you can accept the answer if that answers your question.

Answer (score 1):

You can train BERT for this type of data or any similar model . POS tagging is not mandatory for all types of model, it just adds more context for better model prediction. 
BERT training github repo : [Link1](https://github.com/kyzhouhzau/BERT-NER)
Mostly the models for training NER use [CoNLL-2003 dataset](https://github.com/kyzhouhzau/BERT-NER/tree/master/data) format where POS tags are not necessary. 
There are other architectures for training NER such as XLNET. You can also checkout the latest [Hugging face](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers) library for easy implementation of different architectures.